# Cauchy Schwartz type inequality for $C^{\ast}$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $a_1, a_2, b_1$ and $b_2$ nonzero elements of $\mathcal{A}$. Then it is not difficult to see that

> $\vert \vert a_1b_1+a_2b_2 \vert \vert^2 \leq (\vert \vert a_1 \vert \vert^2 +\vert \vert a_2 \vert \vert^2 ) (\vert \vert b_1 \vert \vert^2 +\vert \vert b_2 \vert \vert^2) $

Does the above inequality becomes an equality in case $a_1, a_2, b_1$ and $b_2$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: The inequality you wrote down is really a combination of three inequalities. Just write the conditions under which each inequality is an equality. I’m not sure much more can be said.

Comment: @DavidGao: I have made the question more precise.

Comment: The statement isn’t even true for scalars. Just take $a_1 = a_2 = b_1 = 1$ and $b_2 = -1$, say.

Answer (score 0):

No. Pick $x$ to be a nonzero element whose square is $0$. Say, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Let $a_1 = a_2 = b_1 = b_2 = x$. Then the LHS is $0$ but the RHS is $4\|x\|^4 \neq 0$.